# Is there any way to get user-wise list of flags?

Tags: support, feature-request

I want to do an analysis on our site on moderator aspect. I want to see the user lists who are flagging most (asc or desc order). Is that possible to view ?

Comment: have updated my answer with a working link

Comment: Are you talking flags or close votes?

Comment: @DavidManners flags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will probably find something for it on https://data.stackexchange.com/magento/queries

It may be a bit more complicated to build a query giving you exactly what you want.

**Update**

have build the Query for this
https://data.stackexchange.com/magento/query/351905/flags-per-user

Comment: I already checked and the only flag related data there is `PendingFlags`, so I guess that means "No".

Comment: Thanks for this. :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure maybe a mod could get a list but there are badges for flags so you could get a slight idea as to who flags and how often.